# How to add PlotLegends only once in a Table[Plot[]]?

Tags: plotting, legending

How do I obtain only one Legend in the following case? I would like to obtain only one "a" and one "b" legend on the side, with two different colors. This means that I want a colored legend for 10 z^i group and one for 10i*z group.

```
Show[Flatten[{Table[
Plot[{10 z^i, 10 i*z}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}], {i, 0, 5, 1}]}]]
```

[image]

What I would like is:

[image]

I have tried the Option:

```
  If[i == 1, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: you could use [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) but I am not sure if this is what you are looking for; you seem to have six pairs of (parametric) functions you plot over the range `{-1,1}`; perhaps you would consider plotting each pair separately with one legend per plot if the labels 'a' and 'b' are not carrying some information or you could eg plot them all together using the specific values of `i` that generate each function in the legend

Comment: @user42582 maybe the edit is more clear?

Comment: @AndreaG take a look now at my answer. I think I got the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Evaluate`  in `Plot` with a value for `PlotStyle`

```
 Plot[
   Evaluate@Table[{10 z^i, 10 i*z}, {i, 0, 5, 1}], 
   {z, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Take[ColorData[68, "ColorList"], 2], 
   PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}
  ]
```

seems to produce the requested effect

[image]

In the documentation for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) there are explicit use cases for plotting *several functions*, together.

In this situation, I am not perfectly sure why the proposed solution works since we are dealing with *pairs* of functions (the input to `Plot` is a matrix-a list of lists).

Nevertheless, pairing `Evaluate` with an explicit option for [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) works :)

Since the pair of colors provided in `PlotStyle` is cycled over the available input functions, it is not implausible to assume that `Plot` treats the lsit of *pairs* of functions as a flattened list of functions.

Comment: imagine now I wanted to use Filling to get filled region between each curve and a corresponding line at a height i (which then depends on the iterator i); how would I combine Filling with this requirement, now that Plot is before Table and iteration has been closed?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but if you evaluate `funcs = Table[{10 z^i, i, 10 i*z, i}, {i, 0, 5, 1}]` and then use `Table[Plot[Evaluate@funcs[[i + 1]], {z, -1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {i, Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.3]]}, 
 3 -> {i, Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.3]]}}], {i, 0, 5, 
  1}]`, perhaps you'll get what you're looking for; using `Filling` in the original multi-plot gets things too crowded to make out any detail

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?:

```
Plot[{10 z^# & /@ Range[0, 5], 10 #*z & /@ Range[0, 5]}, {z, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {a, b}]
```

[image]